# Delegate between ViewControllers on TabBar not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I have a tabbar, the first tab has `HomeViewController` and the second tab has navigationcontroller has two ViewControllers - `CheckOutViewController` and `PaymentViewController`.

I am trying to add a delegate on `PaymentViewController` which allows me to update `HomeViewController`.

However, the delegate method on the `HomeViewController` is not getting called.

**PaymentViewController**

```
@protocol PaymentViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void)paymentSuccessfull :(BOOL)isSuccessfull;
@end

@interface PaymentViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <PaymentViewControllerDelegate> paymentDelegate;

-(void)orderProcessed
{
    [paymentDelegate paymentSuccessfull : YES];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated :YES];
}
```

**HomeViewController.m**

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController<PaymentViewControllerDelegate>

// I do not know how to assign delegate here in the tabbar
-(void)paymentSuccessfull:(BOOL)isSuccessfull
{
   NSLog(@"success");
}
```

Comment: Have you used an instance of PaymentViewController in HomeViewController ?

Comment: No I did not use, since tab bar is used to viewcontrollers transition.

Comment: You can use that delegate methods because you are not using an instance of PaymentViewController inside HomeViewController, but if you want to call that method inside HomeViewController you can use NSNotificationCenter and post a notification inside orderProcessed and catch that into HomeViewController.

Comment: @hotspring did it help ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is that you have some structure like this:

> Tabbar Controller:
>
> - HomeViewController
> - NavigationController
>
>   - PaymentViewController
>   - CheckOutViewController

Now since you've added protocol to **PaymentViewController**, according to your structure, **the delegate method should be called on the Controller from where you are instantiating the PaymentViewController**(I guess in your case that might be NavigationController/Tabbar Controller).
So,in one of these controller **where you would have instantiated PaymentViewController from Storyboard, you would also have to specify that the class conforms to the delegate as well**.

It will be something like:

```
paymentViewControllerObj.delegate = self;
```

I think this should help you out or give you the direction.

Comment: check this for more clarity
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c